# Every operator $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ where $V$ is a $\mathbb C-$vector space has an eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a $\mathbb C-$vector space of finite dimension (let say $n$) and $T\in \mathcal L(V)$. Then $T$ has at least one eigenvalue.

I don't understand the proof.

The list $(v,T(v),...,T^n(v))$ is linearly dependent, i.e. there is $\alpha _i$ not all zero s.t. $$\alpha _0v+\alpha _1T+...+\alpha _nT^n(v)=0$$
for all $v$. Let $\alpha _m\neq 0$ the biggest one i.e. $\alpha _k=0$ for all $k>m$. Then $$0=\alpha _0v+...+\alpha _mT^m(v)=c(T-\lambda _1I)...(T-\lambda _mI)v,$$
and thus there is $j$ s.t. $T-\lambda _jI$ is not injective.

Question : I don't understand why there is $j$ s.t. $T-\lambda _jI$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product of a finite number of injective linear maps is injective. Since $0$ is not injective it follows that one of the factors on the right is not injective.